# Create assembly with permission_set safe

Tags: sql-server, clr, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to deploy a .NET assembly to SQL Server 2008 R2 database, but I'm just hitting this error:

> Deploy error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6509, Level 16, State 31, Line 1 An error occurred while gathering metadata from assembly 'Assembly' with HRESULT 0x80004005.

Now the tricky part is that I've made sure that the framework version is correct, and I have a separate trivial CLR database project from which I add and test things to see if I can isolate the issue (I can't). I've even written a tool which uses `Mono.Cecil` and `PEVerify` to ensure that I adhere to the programming model restrictions that apply to CLR projects in the database. I'm obviously missing something but I don't know how to debug this, why can't SQL Server just tell me why it fails?

Isn't there something I can do to get more verbose output why SQL Server rejects the assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of debugging this is what I did.

Drawing from experience I used Cecil to rewrite the assembly, cancelling out methods by just replacing all method bodies with simply `throw new NotImplementedException` ignoring all constructors (initialization is a bit tricky and just can't just kill the method body of a constructor). After doing this the assembly was installed successfully. I didn't know what was the problem but I knew it had something to do with code. This was my assumption all along.

To find the actual method, I used a binary search. I replaced half of the methods in the assembly and if the error was not there I went left, otherwise right as long as I had a problem until I found the smallest set of methods that were responsible for the error. Given that it was more than 2000 methods and I took about 1-2 seconds to test each configuration, it saved a lot of time.

I managed to zero down on a single method rather easily and here it is (from what I could tell of my findings, this had to be in a generic class as well).

```
class Hashtable<K, V>
{
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var hashtable = new Hashtable();
        return hashtable
            .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<K, V>((K)x.Key, (V)x.Value))
            .GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Nothing in this code really results in any IL that's invalid, even though there's plenty of transformations applied by the compiler. If you put this in a database CLR assembly it will reject the assembly with an `access denied` error with without any further information.

Eventually, I'm gonna file this as a bug with Microsoft, the error message should not be `access denied` and furthermore this code is actually allowed because it doesn't do anything which isn't allowed under the safe permission set.

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste the CREATE DDL statements please? Did you write the CREATE statement yourself? It looks like you may have used the auto-deploy from Visual Studio. Try it manually. 
Please give details on the assembly, does it access external data?

Comment: No external data, it's a simple `create assembly [assembly] from 0x... with permission set = safe;` I've figured it out though but I'm still not sure why this is a problem but I know how to work around it.